# Java Upload file Rest Template

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I need to upload a file through the spring MVC rest template for the below params shown in the image.
[image: Request Details]

I have tried different approaches but it's not working giving exception 401 Unauthorized.
I need code that uploads files through spring MVC RestTemplate.
I have shared my code below which is not working.I have tried different ways to attach file but they are not working please check my code.

**My Code Sample:**

```js
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadPEFile", method = { RequestMethod.POST}, 
                produces = "application/json")
        @ResponseBody
        public String uploadPEFile(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
            JsonResponse objResponse = null;
            String enterpriseId = "";
            String enterpriseName = "";
            String type = "";
            String productId = "";
            String userIds = "";
            String title = "";
            String description = "";
            String date = "";
            String externalUrl = "";
            String presenterName = "";
            try {

                enterpriseId = request.getParameter("enterpriseId");
                enterpriseName = request.getParameter("enterpriseName");
                type = request.getParameter("type");
                productId = request.getParameter("productId");
                userIds = request.getParameter("userIds");
                title = request.getParameter("title");
                description = request.getParameter("description");
                date = request.getParameter("date");
                if(date != null && !date.isEmpty())
                {
                    String [] dateArray = date.split(" ");
                    date = dateArray[2]+" "+getMonth(dateArray[1])+", "+dateArray[3];
                }
                externalUrl = request.getParameter("externalURL");
                presenterName = request.getParameter("presenterName");
                JsonObject jsonBody = new JsonObject();
                jsonBody.addProperty("title", title);
                jsonBody.addProperty("description", description);
                jsonBody.addProperty("date", date);
                jsonBody.addProperty("external_url", externalUrl);
                jsonBody.addProperty("presenter_name", presenterName);
                String cmsDeviceId = PortalUtil.getPropertyValue("cms.device.id");
            
                        if (file != null) {
                    final String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
                    
                    ByteArrayResource fileAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
                        @Override
                        public String getFilename() {
                            return filename;
                        }
                    };
                    String filePath = "/persivia edge/"+type+"/"+filename;
                    File userFile = new File(System.getProperty(PortalConstants.cdnPath) + filePath);
                    if(!userFile.exists()) {
                        userFile.mkdirs();
                    }
                    file.transferTo(userFile);
                    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                    body.add("device_id",cmsDeviceId);
//                  body.add("attachment",fileAsResource);
//                  body.add("attachment",new MultipartInputStreamFileResource(file.getInputStream(), file.getOriginalFilename()));
                    body.add("attachment",new FileSystemResource(filePath));
                    
                    body.add("source", "web");
                    body.add("filename", filename);
                    body.add("enterprise_id", enterpriseId);
                    body.add("enterpriseName", enterpriseName);
                    body.add("type", type);
                    body.add("product_id",productId);
                    body.add("userIds",userIds);
                    body.add("body", jsonBody.toString());
                    
                    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                    String requestUrl = PortalUtil.getPropertyValue("cms.api.url")+"wp-json/wp/v2/upload_content";
                    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(requestUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
                    httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                    JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
                    objResponse = JsonResponse.build(ResponseStatus.status200, ResponseStatus.message200,
                            "Logo info updated successfully", data);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());

                objResponse = JsonResponse.build(ResponseStatus.status500, ResponseStatus.message500,
                        e.getMessage(), null);

                httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            return new Gson().toJson(objResponse);
        }
```

Comment: Provide the code that's giving you an exception rather than just stating it... `401 Unauthorized` occurs when you have something wrong with the security token or  authorization header

Comment: @Ryednap code sample updated

Comment: does the error occurs while creating a request at `/uploadPEFile` endpoint or does the error occurs during the execution of this statement `String response = restTemplate.postForObject(requestUrl, requestEntity, String.class);` Anyways it's hard to track `401 Unauthorized` like this. If the error occurs during `/uploadPeFile` then you should be having spring security declining authorization at this endpoint, and if the error occurs during the execution of `RestTemplate` this means that the post request requires auth header

Comment: error occurs during the execution of this statement
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(requestUrl, requestEntity, String.class);
@Ryednap

Comment: Then the request `requestUrl` requires some authorization. It seems you need to provide auth header in the request of your `RestTemplate`. Kindly check and confirm first if you have access to the server handling the request at the `requestURl` endpoint.

Comment: @Ryednap I have accessed this service from postman without authorization.

Comment: Can you check if there's any authorization on the `Authorization` tab of the postman? Look `401 Unauthorized` doesn't occur by any other means. It's not like `400` or `500` error.

Comment: @Ryednap no there is no Authorization header or any authorization on the postman. I have checked. one more thing this endpoint I am accessing is written in PHP this might be the reason.

Comment: I don't know I am out of ideas now. Just looking at the information you have provided it's hard to know about the bug.